# Is there a way to find 'Call' function for time series data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, logical-operators

My sample data looks like this.

```
Date        14 Day Moving Average   Upper Band  Lower Band  Average_Price
2017-05-15  773.170797              1054.136298 492.205297  917.04
2017-05-16  773.170797              1054.136298 492.205297  897.29
2017-05-17  773.170797              1054.136298 492.205297  887.49
2017-05-18  773.170797              1054.136298 492.205297  902.17
2017-05-19  773.170797              1054.136298 492.205297  842.98
```

'Buy' if the stock price is below the lower Bollinger band

'Liquidate Short' if the stock price is between the lower and middle Bollinger band

'Hold Short/ Liquidate Buy' if the stock price is between the middle and upper Bollinger band

'Short' if the stock price is above the upper Bollinger band

How shall i proceed further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: The answer to my question is not there on duplicate that you have marked. @AlexandreB

Comment: After edition, it's right. What is the question ?